# Add Unique Constraint in Entity Designe

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, database-design

I was wondering how to add a unique constraint while in the Entity Designer in Visual Studio 2015. All the answers that I've found only talk about adding a unique constraint in the generated C# code or in the generated sql.

Is there a way to do this in the designer itself?

Comment: is this `db first` or what?

Comment: No, designer first. I want my code and database to be generated from my model diagram.